Nuxt 2 QR link redirect to external one
I have QR codes, that exist on many products. Now link from QR is not actually. I need redirect old link to new external one.
I use Nuxt 2 and  Vue 2.
I try do that:
1) // nuxt.config.js


routeRules: {
  '/api/images/image.pdf': { redirect: 'https://example.com' },
},



2) //middleware/redirect.global.js


export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  if (to.path === '/api/images/image.pdf') {
    return navigateTo('//example.com', { redirectCode: 301 })
  }
})



Both of them do not work. How can I implement redirect from QR link to external link using Nuxt 2?

Can you share a minimal reproducible code, so that it would be easier to help? Also can you check whether to.path in the middleware is having a correct value
